# Python top layer for loop only running once instead of iterating over list

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, data-science

I am trying to iterate over a list if Items and their respective number of items sold in order to create a list of items sold for each item last month. To do this I create a nested for loop that takes the items sold of last month for each item and appends it to a list. however when I run the loop the top layer only runs once and does not iterate through the rest of the items. the output of counter is 1 when it should be then len of the lists

```
count=0
obj=zip(Grouped_DF['item_id'], Grouped_DF['item_cnt_day'])
item_cnt_day_minus_1=[]
counter=0
for item, itm_cnt in obj:
    counter+=1
    for x,y in obj:
        if item==x and count==0:
            count+=1
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(0)
        if item==x and count==1:
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(itm_cnt)
            count+=1
            count=y
        if item==x and count>1:
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(y)
            count=y
    count=0
```

Comment: btw I'm sure that `count+=1; count=y` is not what you want inside the second `if`.

Comment: Ok, you are iterating twice through the same `zip` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate separate `zip` objects for each for loop:

```py
item_cnt_day_minus_1=[]
counter = 0
count = 0
for item, itm_cnt in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [42, 43, 44]):  # sample data I invented
    counter += 1
    for x,y in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [42, 43, 44]):
        if item == x and count == 0:
            count += 1
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(0)
        if item == x and count == 1:
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(itm_cnt)
            count += 1
            count = y
        if item == x and count > 1:
            item_cnt_day_minus_1.append(y)
            count = y
    count=0

print(counter, item_cnt_day_minus_1)
```

Output:

```
3 [0, 42, 42, 0, 43, 43, 0, 44, 44]
```